# How to change the text color of only first element of spinner?

Tags: android, layout, colors, spinner

I have to change the color of spinner first element which is displayed as the default element.
Tried various methods not working.
provide a working solution.

Comment: you need to set custom spinner_item layout . show what you tried

Comment: @ShivanshSaxena Whatever you have tried or what is now are you trying include that code.

Comment: follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513126/spinner-background-color-with- dropdowndown-icon/44513290#44513290

Comment: check this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner

Answer (score 0):

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner) solution after some modifications, this answer will helps you to change first `spinner` of item.

In onCreate, calling common method as `setSpinnerValue` :

```
ArrayList<String> testarray = new ArrayList<String>();
        testarray.add("item0");
        testarray.add("item1");
        testarray.add("item2");
        testarray.add("item3");
        setSpinnerValue(testarray,timeSpinner,arrayAdapter);
```

Here, i have created Common method with `arrayList`, `spinner` and `arrayAdapter` as parameter for setting spinner items in `adapter`.

```
public void setSpinnerValue(final ArrayList<String> list, Spinner spinner, ArrayAdapter<String> adapter)
    {
        try {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TimePicker_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list) {

                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    String val = String.valueOf(list.get(position));
                    boolean isFalse = val.contains(":False");
                    return !isFalse;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = convertView;
                    if (v == null) {
                        Context mContext = this.getContext();
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
                    }
                    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    String val = String.valueOf(list.get(position));
                    tv.setText(val.replace(":False", ""));

                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            tv.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
                            break;

                        default:
                            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                            break;
                    }

                    return v;
                }
            };
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setSelection(0, false);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Getting output as below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the people who struggle to get this working, this is the **Kotlin** solution.

1. Subclass the `ArrayAdapter` class

   ```
    class CustomArrayAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: List<String>) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, objects) {

            override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
                val view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent)
                if (view is TextView) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        view.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(parent.context, R.color.red_color_1))
                    } else {
                        view.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(parent.context, R.color.blue_color_1))
                    }
                }
                return view
            }
    }
   ```

Connect to adapter to your list:

```
fun setAdapter() {
    CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, buildItems()).also { adapter ->
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_list_item)
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        binding.mySpinner.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the list is a `RecyclerView`. It means, essentially, that if you change one of the items color, you gotta change the color to all of the other items also (if the position == 0 AND if the position != 0, cause the position == 0 item will be used again and again)

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            if (position == 0) {
                (view as TextView).setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorgray))
            }
```

try to set position of zero on itemSelected overriden function ..